# The recovery server could not be contacted while installing Mojave

Tags: install, recovery

Just needed a bit of help debugging.

This is a machine that came with Yosemite OS and I had updated to Mojave. So  I want to wipe and install a new Mojave on it because you can't install Yosemite on APFS.

I'm trying to install Mojave with internet recovery and there is currently no OS installed at all on the machine.

Things I've tried:
- changing the date in the utilities terminal. The way I did this was opened terminal and typed date 0605111117 and then cmd+q then selected Reinstall MacOS
- pinged google.com to verify a good internet connection
- tried to delete the Mojave installer in / but it requires root and I don't know how to do that as root in internet recovery mode